# return File() with ASP.NET MVC2 shows incorrect downloadName

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, download

I'm having trouble downloading file with asp.net mvc2. This is how I do it in my download action:

```
return File(resultBytes, Settings.Default.CsvFileContentType, downloadName);
```

The problem is with the downloadName, this is how I generate it:

`var downloadName = string.Format("{0}_{1}{2}", vModel.CompetitionEvent.Ends.Year, Text.RemoveDiacriticalChars(vModel.Competition.Title), Settings.Default.CsvFileExtension);`

and when I debug, downloadName value is: **"2011_SS C/C++/Pascal (I.).csv"**
but what I get upon downlaod is: **"Pascal (I.).csv"**.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply cannot have a "/" character in a filename. Windows filenames in general cannot contain "\/:*?"<>|", so I assume the downloadname is being automatically truncated to adhere to this limitation.

Try replacing the "/" with a hypen ("-") instead, and see what happens :)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that. Thanks!